# How to export jshint config file from WebStorm

Tags: configuration, webstorm, jshint

I used to work alone on a project. I used to use WebStorm's JSHint plugin for code quality testing.

Now couple of friends joined me so I thought to create a .jshintrc file for all of us to use. But it is quite boring to do it manually and I'm perfectly happy with my current settings.

Is there a way to export my project-wide settings in order to share it with co-worker?

Answer (score 1):

JSHint configuration from `Settings(Preferences) | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSHint` is stored in `<project_dir>\.idea\jsLinters\jshint.xml`. You can share this file with your co-workers

Comment: I did not find this file. There were no subdirectories in .idea folder. I am using Mac and latest WebStorm if that is important.

Comment: strange... this configuration has always been written to project .idea\jsLinters\jshint.xml. and I'm also using the latest version. Please check once more - may be, the files/folders are hidden in your file manager?

Comment: Nope. I listed directory from both terminal and finder. I managed to create config with yeoman but this is disappointing.

Comment: might be because your settings are saved on a global level, then instead of checking at project level, look for webstorm preferences :)